# Where can i find draw js file - beginner

Tags: leap-motion

I am going through the following example. The [code is found here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/lknxb).

I need to know where i could find draw.js?

```
<script src='draw.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a head-scratcher for me too, until I realized that it refers to the JS window on the upper right. That script is draw.js :D